# Convert and Subtract two time columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 2 number columns: start_time and seen_time.

```
Start_time          Seen_time 
1345                1520
```

That means start time is 1:45 pm and seen_time is 3:20 pm

I want to subtract columns and result be 1:35 h

Comment: have you tried the DATEDIFF() function?

Comment: Please would you mind to write it's syntax please

Comment: Please show table definition, along with column data types, and complete, and exact sample data.  There is no such thing as a "time" type in oracle.  There is a DATE type, which contains a type component, so your question is unclear.

Comment: @WesDoyle there is no "datediff" function in oracle.

Comment: data type is number 4 digits like 1500 it means 03:00 pm

Comment: use mod 100 arithmetic to get hour, scale by 60 go get minutes, add remainder.  Do same for other time, then subtract, convert back

Comment: And what happens if a new day is spanned?

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun...  Not a way I would ever code for anything serious (although, in fact, it does solve the problem correctly and efficiently). The code is just as unusual (meaning, "don't do this for anything important") as the OP's data model.

```
with
     inputs ( time_from, time_to ) as (
       select   32,  233 from dual union all
       select 1030, 2322 from dual union all
       select 2200, 1130 from dual union all
       select 2030, 3544 from dual union all
       select 1233, 2051 from dual union all
       select 1215, 1360 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select time_from, time_to,
       case when time_from > time_to then 'Error: time_from > time_to'
            when trunc(time_from / 100) > 23 then 'Error: invalid hours in time_from'
            when mod  (time_from , 100) > 59 then 'Error: invalid minutes in time_from'
            when trunc(time_to   / 100) > 23 then 'Error: invalid hours in time_to'
            when mod  (time_to   , 100) > 59 then 'Error: invalid minutes in time_to'
            else to_char(time_to - time_from -
                   case when mod(time_to, 100) < mod(time_from, 100) then 40 else 0 end,
                   'FM00G00L', 'nls_numeric_characters='',:'' nls_currency='' h''')
            end   as time_diff
from   inputs
;

 TIME_FROM    TIME_TO   TIME_DIFF
----------   --------   -----------------------------------
        32        233   02:01 h
      1030       2322   12:52 h
      2200       1130   Error: time_from > time_to
      2030       3544   Error: invalid hours in time_to
      1233       2051   08:18 h
      1215       1360   Error: invalid minutes in time_to

6 rows selected.
```